# Customizing Scroll bar of List Box

Tags: windows, winapi

I am working on a win 32 sample. In that I am using List Box to Display the List of user. I am using the setting the owner draw flag to draw the items. It is working fine.

But I want to customize the scrollbar of the list view. How to do it.
Please let me know how to customize the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollbars are usually native, even for custom draw items. If you really want to customize them, take a look at [this library & tutorial](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/coolscroll).